# Javascript - Which event to listen to know if a popup menu comes up

Tags: javascript

I want to capture events in Javascript like link click, input type, button hit/submit etc and send it to an application (recording user actions). Later I will play those user events and do automation testing.

I have a specific case, that I do not know how to capture the user event. When I bring mouse cursor over menu region, a pop up menu shows up. Let's take an example. In [dev.lmtools.com](https://dev.lmtools.com) site, bring mouse cursor to "**Test Environment**" tab. You will see smething like image below. In that image, you can see the highlighted menu link "**Calculate Endpoints**" that user will click.

My job is to record user event when popup menu shows up and as well when user clicks link "**Calculate Endpoints**". I have explored mouseover, mouseexit, mouseenter, mouseleave event handlers without success. Mouseover generates so many events, so this I want to exclude. Mouseenter fires at page start, when it goes to menu area event does not fire.

I am interseted to know which event I should listen for, what is the unique identifier of element that pops up, identifier of link thats clicked by user, so that I can play afterwards accordingly.

Any help in this regard highly appreciated.

[image: popup menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry)

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe
> changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor
> element or with a top-level document's

For example, you can add a `ID`to the popup container and then, ( Note - I did not ran this code. May have some syntax errors )

```
// definition    
function popupObserver(el, cb) {
      let opt = {
        root: document.documentElement
      }
      let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          cb(entry.intersectionRatio > 0);
        });
      }, opt);
    
      observer.observe(el);
    }
```

then you use above function like,

```
    popupObserver(document.querySelector("#popup_container_id"), trackPopup);

    function trackPopup(isVisible){
      let linkEl = null;

      if(linkEl) {
       linkEl.removeEventListener("click", trackMouseClick)
      }

      if(isVisible) {
        // User hover over the link. capture popup. below code is a dummy code
        tracker.track(EVENT.POPUP_HOVER);
       
        linkEl = document.querySelector("#link_id");
        linkEl.addEventListener("click", trackMouseClick)
      } 
    }

    function trackMouseClick() {
      // dummy code to track link click
      tracker.track(EVENT.LINK_CLICKED)
    }
```

Comment: In line,     "popupObserver(document.querySelector("#popup_container_id"), trackPopup);", is #popup_container_id a hard coded value? I do not know the id of container.  Similarly  in line "inkEl = document.querySelector("#link_id");", is #link_id hard coded?

Comment: you should replace them with your HTML element IDs. For example there should be a `<a>Calculate Endpoints</a>` tag in the drop down menu. So the `#link_id` means you set a id to the above <a> tag. `<a id="link_id">Calculate Endpoints</a>`. Now Javascrpit can refer to that element. Same the `#popup_container_id` is the id of the popup part. Probably it is a `<div>` tag. So add an ID to it.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible for me. Its a generic requiement to record user actions in any site and send those actions to my recorder application. Later I need to generate some scripts for automation testing. So changing id and all not possible in this case.